# How to add an other column to the start menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm not referring to All Programs. I want to add a second column to menu that shows the 'Pinned to Start Menu' icons.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible.

But with [Start Menu 7 PRO](http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html), which is basically the paid version of Vista Start Menu (although distributed via a separate website), one can have multiple columns to the right, organized in tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to add another column in default menu. However I can suggest you one application called "Vista Start Menu" that can help you in adding multiple columns. If you are unable to find solution within default start menu you can try this.

Here is a link to download and home page for the same.
http://www.vistastartmenu.com/

Screenshot link:
http://www.vistastartmenu.com/screenshot.html

Comment: That looks absolutely awful

Comment: @Joe Taylor: Vista Start Menu can be skinned. Don't knock it down, it's a nice start menu replacement.

Comment: @harrymc - Then that screenshot does it an incredible injustice

Comment: thant's for the reply. but you didn't understand i want two columns at the pinned programs. from the screenshot, the first column in the left, over the search box.